# Space Launch System (SLS) costs

Tags: sls

What is a good estimate for SLS' annual fixed cost and variable per flight cost?  What references are used for these costs?

I've seen uncited figures of $1B+/launch variable cost.

Wikipedia quotes a NASA deputy project manager as saying that $500M/launch is a target.  This seems low as the Delta IV Heavy used in the Orion test launch was in that range.

Other estimates cited on Wikipedia range up to $1.9B/launch.

Comment: An unknown is flight rate and how many SLS rockets would be made. The development costs would be amortized over the number of rockets made. For example if development costs were \$30 billion and there were a total of 10 launches, each rockets would bear \$3 billion in development costs.

Comment: Right.  That's why I asked for fixed and variable cost components.  Cheers.

Comment: Here is John Strickland's estimate: http://www.thespacereview.com/article/2330/1 although I've heard SLS apologists saying he's overly pessimistic on the variable cost components.

Comment: Didn't that Delta IV Heavy + Orion cost include the cost of the Orion itself, not just the launch?

Comment: Nope.  \$500m for just the ride.  The Air Force recently paid \$1.74B for 4 Delta IV Heavy launches too.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia states \$500 million per launch, with [this](http://www.nbcnews.com/id/49019843/ns/technology_and_science-space/#.VrBlqSaLe1F) citation. The development budget is [$18 billion](http://www.spacepolicyonline.com/news/new-nasa-crew-transportation-system-to-cost-18-billion-through-2017) (\$10 billion for the actual SLS rocket), and that is a more reliable number as it is a budget. However, a development budget is always a lower limit. [This site](http://www.nbcnews.com/id/44517102/ns/technology_and_science-space/t/nasa-unveils-giant-rocket-design-future-odysseys/#.VrBowCaLe1E) for instance, provides an total development cost estimate of \$35 billion.

[The space review](http://www.thespacereview.com/article/2330/1) says \$1 billion per launch, \$1.5 billion if development costs are included. Their citation is [this](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v472/n7341/full/472038d.html) study

Comment: Hi @Hohmannfan, any update on the total development cost? I know that US gov released further $5 billion last March to NASA for SLS and Orion

Comment: It has eaten a few extra billions, but there are no big changes. As there are many years left before we have flight ready hardware the end result is still not easy to predict.